# What is wrong with my writing data to a csv file in c#?

Tags: c#, export-to-csv

I am attempting to write highscores from the game i am building in Unity to a CSV file. So far i have gotten this far:

```
    {
        string filepath = Application.dataPath;
        string newFileName = (Application.dataPath + "highscore.csv");
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(newFileName);
        writer.WriteLine("Score,Time");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(scoresAndSeconds[i, 0].ToString() + "," + scoresAndSeconds[i, 1].ToString());
        } 
    }
```

I am succeeding in creating the CSV file when I call the function, but nothing at all is being written. No errors are being thrown from the code.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint on the loop statement and see what the values are?

Comment: So far i haven't even thought about the loop, as writer.Writeline("Score, Time") isn't writing anything.

Comment: You are likely not flushing the stream, and using streams incorrectly  `using StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(newFileName);`

Comment: Working fine now - what is the correct etiquette once a question has been answered on here?

Comment: @shadowgamer99 if your problem is solved, mark as correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to flush the stream. To achieve that, just use the `using` statement

```
using StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(newFileName);
writer.WriteLine("Score,Time");
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    writer.WriteLine(scoresAndSeconds[i, 0].ToString() + "," + scoresAndSeconds[i, 1].ToString());
}
```

Note you might want to look at a Csv library for more extensive CSV support